# Entity Framework: Executing a stored procedure that returns different columns and column data types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to execute a stored procedure this way:

```
var filterValues= context.Database.SqlQuery<FilterProcedureDTO>( 
 "[dbo].[sp_GetFilterValues] @FieldID", new SqlParameter("FieldID", filterID))
 .ToList();
```

the issue is the filter values that come up have diffrent column name with each call as the user changes the filter on the view,though all come up as objects with an int column and string column,it seems they are bound to the specified model ie FilterProcedureDTO..which looks like

```
  public class FilterProcedureDTO
    {
        public FilterProcedureDTO() {
        //empty constructor
        }
        public int production_lineID { get; set; }
        public string production_line_desc { get; set; }
    }
```

so if the call produces **taskID** and **task_desc** this wont work anymore.
Another thing is some IDs are **int32** and some are **int16** so the code is not executing  perfectly because of periodic exceptions

How can I get the stored procedure to return generic objects,just recognising the datatypes and not variable names too?

Comment: A stored procedure that returns varying column names is untenable. You'll need to alter it so that there's at least some congruity between various executions.

Comment: @Chris I will take your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SQLQuery` method always attempts the column-to-property matching based on property name.

So you need to change your stored procedure so that it always returns the same name and datatype. You should be able to do that using aliases and casting in the sql.

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987939/150342

Comment: Thanks Colin,It makes sense,and looks  viable too, let me implement it and will get back to you

Comment: I did implement it and it worked,now I can just use the DTO to receive the data  a stored procedure returning the columns **id** and **description** always                                                                                   'public class FilterProcedureDTO
    {

        public FilterProcedureDTO() {
        
        }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }' <br/>