# Working with multiple resultset in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

While retrieving the results using stored procedure how can I retrieve and store multiple result set in view model in .net core

For e.g. from stored procedure I am returning records for below two queries

```
Select * LMS_Survey
Select * from LMS_SurveyQuestion
Select * from LMS_SurveyQuestionOptionChoice
```

and below is view model for two tables

```
public class LMS_SurveyTraineeViewModel
{
    public LMS_SurveyDetailsViewModel SurveyDetailsViewModel { get; set; }
    public LMS_SurveyQuestionsViewModel SurveyQuestionsViewModel { get; set; }
    public LMS_SurveyQuestionOptionChoiceViewModel SurveyQuestionOptionChoiceViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I am executing the stored procedure

```
public List<LMS_SurveyTraineeViewModel> GetTraineeSurvey(int surveyID)
        {
            try
            {
                List<LMS_SurveyTraineeViewModel> modelList = new List<LMS_SurveyTraineeViewModel>();

                modelList = dbcontext.Set<LMS_SurveyTraineeViewModel>().FromSql("LMSSP_GetTraineeSurvey @surveyID = {0},@LanguageID = {1}", surveyID, AppTenant.SelectedLanguageID).ToList();

                return modelList;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

How can stored the multiple result set using stored procedure in view model ?

Comment: Can you paste a full code snippet that would show how you are calling sproc to retrieve data at the moment?

Comment: If your issue is mapping the result of the stored procedure to an entity/a class, see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929113/how-to-use-entity-framework-to-map-results-of-a-stored-procedure-to-entity-with.

Comment: @Ignas I have updated the code !

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Currently, EF Core doesn't not support this.  There is an open issue to address this.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/8127

**Update 12th Sep 2018:** This is still not a priority for EF Core even for release 3.0; so best use Dapper or plain ADO.NET when you have multiple results scenario

**Update 25th Jun 2020:** still on the backlog for EF Core even for release 5.0; so best use Dapper or plain ADO.NET when you have multiple results scenario

**Update 7th Feb 2021:** still on the backlog for EF Core

**Update 8th Aug 2022:** still on the backlog for EF Core, looks like its not a high priority use-case.  Recommend to follow alternatives like using straight ADO.NET or Dapr or the below workaround for this

***In the interim an alternative solution can be achieved via extension method(s)***

```
public static async Task<IList<IList>> MultiResultSetsFromSql(this DbContext dbContext, ICollection<Type> resultSetMappingTypes, string sql, params object[] parameters)
{
    var resultSets = new List<IList>();

    var connection = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
    var parameterGenerator = dbContext.GetService<IParameterNameGeneratorFactory>()
                                        .Create();
    var commandBuilder = dbContext.GetService<IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory>()
                                    .Create();

    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
    {
        var generatedName = parameterGenerator.GenerateNext();
        if (parameter is DbParameter dbParameter)
            commandBuilder.AddRawParameter(generatedName, dbParameter);
        else
            commandBuilder.AddParameter(generatedName, generatedName);
    }

    using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = sql;
    command.Connection = connection;
    for (var i = 0; i < commandBuilder.Parameters.Count; i++)
    {
        var relationalParameter = commandBuilder.Parameters[i];
        relationalParameter.AddDbParameter(command, parameters[i]);
    }

    var materializerSource = dbContext.GetService<IEntityMaterializerSource>();
    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        await connection.OpenAsync();

    using var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    foreach (var pair in resultSetMappingTypes.Select((x, i) => (Index: i, Type: x)))
    {
        var i = pair.Index;
        var resultSetMappingType = pair.Type;
        if (i > 0 && !(await reader.NextResultAsync()))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("No result set at index {0}, unable to map to {1}.", i, resultSetMappingType));

        var type = resultSetMappingType;
        var entityType = dbContext.GetService<IModel>()
                                    .FindEntityType(type);
        if (entityType == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Unable to find a an entity type (or query type) matching '{0}'", type));
        var relationalTypeMappingSource = dbContext.GetService<IRelationalTypeMappingSource>();
        var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                                .Select(x => new
                                {
                                    Index = x,
                                    Name = reader.GetName(x)
                                })
                                .ToList();
        var relationalValueBufferFactoryFactory = dbContext.GetService<IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory>();
        int discriminatorIdx = -1;
        var discriminatorProperty = entityType.GetDiscriminatorProperty();
        var entityTypes = entityType.GetDerivedTypesInclusive();

        var instanceTypeMapping = entityTypes.Select(et => new
        {
            EntityType = et,
            Properties = et.GetProperties()
                            .Select(x =>
                            {
                                var column = columns.FirstOrDefault(y => string.Equals(y.Name,
                                                                                        x.GetColumnName() ?? x.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Unable to find a column mapping property '{0}'.", x.Name));

                                if (x == discriminatorProperty)
                                    discriminatorIdx = column.Index;
                                return new TypeMaterializationInfo(x.PropertyInfo.PropertyType, x, relationalTypeMappingSource, column.Index);
                            })
                            .ToArray()
        })
        .Select(x => new
        {
            EntityType = x.EntityType,
            Properties = x.Properties,
            ValueBufferFactory = relationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.Create(x.Properties)
        })
        .ToDictionary(e => e.EntityType.GetDiscriminatorValue() ?? e.EntityType, e => e)
        ;

        var resultSetValues = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type));
        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            var instanceInfo = discriminatorIdx < 0 ? instanceTypeMapping[entityType] : instanceTypeMapping[reader[discriminatorIdx]];

            var valueBuffer = instanceInfo.ValueBufferFactory.Create(reader);

            var materializationAction = materializerSource.GetMaterializer(instanceInfo.EntityType);
            resultSetValues.Add(materializationAction(new MaterializationContext(valueBuffer, dbContext)));
        }

        resultSets.Add(resultSetValues);
    }

    return resultSets;
}
```

**And the extension typed methods**

```
public static async Task<(IReadOnlyCollection<T1> FirstResultSet, IReadOnlyCollection<T2> SecondResultSet)> MultiResultSetsFromSql<T1, T2>(this DbContext dbContext, string sql, params object[] parameters)
{
    var resultSetMappingTypes = new[]
                                {
                                        typeof(T1), typeof(T2)
                                };

    var resultSets = await MultiResultSetsFromSql(dbContext, resultSetMappingTypes, sql, parameters);

    return ((IReadOnlyCollection<T1>)resultSets[0], (IReadOnlyCollection<T2>)resultSets[1]);
}

public static async Task<(IReadOnlyCollection<T1> FirstResultSet, IReadOnlyCollection<T2> SecondResultSet, IReadOnlyCollection<T3> ThirdResultSet)> MultiResultSetsFromSql<T1, T2, T3>(this DbContext dbContext, string sql, params object[] parameters)
{
    var resultSetMappingTypes = new[]
                                {
                                        typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3)
                                };

    var resultSets = await MultiResultSetsFromSql(dbContext, resultSetMappingTypes, sql, parameters);

    return ((IReadOnlyCollection<T1>)resultSets[0], (IReadOnlyCollection<T2>)resultSets[1], (IReadOnlyCollection<T3>)resultSets[2]);
}
```

Comment: Is this still on the backlog?

Comment: @mehaboob looks like its still on the backlog and not targeted for any release

Answer (score 1):

Currently, EF Core doesn't not support this. see this example for retrieve multiple result sets. 
https://github.com/nilendrat/EfCoreMultipleResults/

Answer (score 1):

It works with this tiny change on EF core 5 according to Ricky G answer

change

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

to

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

and as sql parameter value for this extension method type your stored procedure name "dbo.testproc"
example of usage:

```
var t1 = await _context.MultiResultSetsFromSql(new [] {typeof(proctestprocResult) },"dbo.testproc", sqlParameters);
```

works for me